How to disable the structured command editor for IntelliJ run configurations?
Using 2024.3.
I find the structured editor for the "run" field in a run configuration to be very frustrating.
It ignores normal editing keys (home, end, etc.) even ignores spaces sometimes when you're trying to add an option manually.
My workaround is to copy/paste into an external text editor, edit the command there, then copy back to IDEA (thankfully ctrl-a still works).
Is there option, or even any IDEA-registry entry to make this field just use normal text editing functionality?
